# meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf returning tensor instead of ModelOutput

Tags: huggingface-transformers, llama

I am using the [Llama-2-7b-hf](https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf) model with the `model.generate` function from the transformers library (v4.38.2) and it's returning the outputs as a single tensor, instead of the ModelOutput I expected.

I have a copy of the model stored locally:

```
[Llama-2-7b-hf]$ ls -1
config.json
generation_config.json
LICENSE.txt
model-00001-of-00002.safetensors
model-00002-of-00002.safetensors
model.safetensors.index.json
README.md
Responsible-Use-Guide.pdf
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config.json
tokenizer.json
tokenizer.model
USE_POLICY.md
```

This is the code where the model is initialized and then called:

```
model_path = "Llama-2-7b-hf"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, return_dict_in_generate=True, local_files_only=True).to(device)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(engine, local_files_only=True)

input_ids = tokenizer(model_path, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to(device)
outputs = model.generate(input_ids, top_k=1, max_length=max_len, num_return_sequences=1, output_scores=True)
sequences, scores = outputs.sequences, outputs.scores
```

I have used this code with several other models like [Mistral](https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1) and [Occiglot](https://huggingface.co/occiglot/occiglot-7b-eu5) and they return ModelOutput objects with these attributes, `sequences` and `scores`, but not Llama. Can anyone help me understand what is wrong?